# get a new output by mixing 2 queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have one query that output me a list of companies, their permits, and their permit start date. I have another list that output me a lot of companies, with let's say, all the activities '01' and their date. I would like to mash these 2 to get the results of every company that had activities '01' before the start date of their permit.

So I should see in my output query for example:

Company that had activities '01' ONLY before the start date of their permit.

Is it possible?

Comment: Try building query that joins tables and WHERE criteria: `[ActivtityDate]<[StartDate] AND Activity = "01"`. Basically same advice offered in your duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71454759/get-output-by-mixing-2-queries. No attempt to solve and no code provided for analysis and no sample data. Question is not improved.

Comment: I posted the question but it didn't worked when I did. I didn't know it worked finaly. Wasn't on purpose!